# Terraform granting access on GCP Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to find what is the difference between the two terraform modules, google_bigquery_dataset_access and google_bigquery_dataset_iam, and I cannot seem to find clear information or maybe I am looking at it wrong. Both would give permissions on a dataset.

Could someone shed some light?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With the both you can set roles on Dataset for users. But

- With `google_bigquery_dataset_access` you can define/grant [authorized view](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/share-access-views)
- With `google_bigquery_dataset_iam`, you can define IAM and bindings in an idiomatic way and a more modern way

*IMO, `access` is the legs of the BigQuery legacy version. If you can avoid to use it for IAM bindings, only for authorized view, it's better!*